# Get nested dictonary name by value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to get the nested dictionary value by inputting a value in the said nested dictonary

example

```
users = {"Pepe": {"Name": "Pepe Perez", "ID": "A1234"}, "Juan": {"Name": "Gomez", "ID": "B4321"}}
find-name = input("enter id: ")
```

so if the input is "B4321" it should return "Juan"
Any idea of how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: How about looping over the key value pairs and checking if `value["ID"]==var`?

Comment: Perhaps ID should be your key.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generator expression that loops through the dict's items until it finds a value matching your ID. Then return the `next` one. This assumes only one item matches:

```
users = {"Pepe": {"Name": "Pepe Perez", "ID": "A1234"}, "Juan": {"Name": "Gomez", "ID": "B4321"}}
find_name = "B4321"

next((k for k, v in users.items() if v['ID'] == find_name), None)
# 'Juan'
```

This will return `None` if the id is not found. This would be more efficient if you used the `ID` value as the key for the main dict. Then you could just look it up.